# Robot Framework Ride - Keyword to json skips element

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I have a JSON string and when i try to convert it to JSON, so i can use it as variable in a postrequest, a element is missing. Thereafter the post request fails with `"TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"`

The string is:

```
${data}=    Set Variable    {"elementKey":"P690-C0-C3-B1","fields":[{"key":"P690-C1-C2-C1-C1-C1-F0","values":[]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F8","values":["1200"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F9","values":["22000"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F11","values":["I"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F10","values":["2200"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-C0-C0-F0","values":["98-zsg-2"]},{"key":"P690-C1-C0-C0-F1","values":["Personenauto"]},{"key":"P690-C1-C0-C0-F2","values":["ASR - Personenauto VVP"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F6","values":["B"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F7","values":["75"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F4","values":["2"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F5","values":["5"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F2","values":["model"]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F3","values":["2017"]},{"key":"P690-C1-C2-C2-C2-C1-F0","values":[]},{"key":"P690-C0-C2-F1","values":["merk"]}]}
${data}=    to json ${data}
```

Result ${data} = 
`${data} = {u'fields': [{u'values': [], u'key': u'P690-C1-C2-C1-C1-C1-F0'}, {u'values': [u'1200'], u'key': u'P690-C0-C2-F8'}, {u'values': [u'22000'], u'key': u'P690-C0-C2-F9'}, {u'values': [u'I'], u'key': u'P690...`

As you can see the "elementKey":"P690-C0-C3-B1" is gone. What am i missing here?
Could this also be the reason why my Post Request is failing with `${data} = {}, "TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"?`

Comment: Are you sure `"elementKey":"P690-C0-C3-B1"` is gone? Chances are it is truncated in the output (...)

Comment: How silly of me, instead of being in front of the string it is at the back. Do you know if it matters where it stands? Because when i use this variable in the post request the keyword says ${data} = {}. I hoped the missing element was the solution to my other problem. Hopefully is it equally fixable. Thx for your suggestion

Comment: Could you show your `Post Request` code too?

Comment: Thx! i just found out my mistake, the error came from an other keyword. I deleted to many rows in the testcase.

Comment: @Shizzleliz the position does not matter nor for python's dictionaries (the type you're getting out of "To Json"), nor for json itself.